# Value inside {{}} not updated in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-digest

There is a functionality where we use nested angular directives. I am adding a simplified example where the behavior can be observed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div>
        This is the first directive
        <first-directive my-val="9">
        </first-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.directive("firstDirective",function(){
    return {
            template:'<second-directive val-new={{myVal}}></second-directive>',
            scope:{
                myVal:'@'
            },
            //transclude:true,
            link: {
                pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
                        scope.myVal=scope.myVal+"1";
                    }
            }
    }
});

app.directive("secondDirective",function(){
    return{
        scope:{
            valNew:'@'
        },

        link:{
            pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
                    console.log(scope.valNew);
                }
        }
    }
});
```

In the console I get the result of the update made in the pre method, but in the html I get the old value.

Console prints: "91"
The html dom contains:

```
    <second-directive val-new="9" class="ng-isolate-scope"></second-directive>>
```

Please help me understand why this difference is observed and how to make these two places consistent

**EDIT**
I am just looking for a way to make the scope variables in the second directive react to the changes made in the linked variables of the first directive's scope. So in some other place when the `myVal` changes, I am looking to make the second directive react to the changes.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I can see that the question is not useful to other readers. Why would any directive need to modify the scope in the preLink function? So why would anyone care about any problems it causes?

Comment: Please don't misunderstand man, you tried to help with the answer as it seems, but since someone else downvoted it, I was just saying the one down voting a post should let the user know the fault he is making, its certainly possible that I am asking a stupid question, but by just downvoting would not help me understand my mistake, right?...actually the situation was complicated, I tried to post a minimal and verifiable reference to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Move the calculation to the template:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.directive("firstDirective",function(){
    return {
            ̶t̶e̶m̶p̶l̶a̶t̶e̶:̶'̶<̶s̶e̶c̶o̶n̶d̶-̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶-̶n̶e̶w̶=̶{̶{̶m̶y̶V̶a̶l̶}̶}̶>̶<̶/̶s̶e̶c̶o̶n̶d̶-̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶>̶'̶
            template:'<second-directive val-new="{{myVal+'1'}}"></second-directive>',
            scope:{
                myVal:'@'
            },
            //transclude:true,
            link: {
                pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
                    ̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶m̶y̶V̶a̶l̶=̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶m̶y̶V̶a̶l̶+̶"̶1̶"̶;̶
                }

            }
    }
});
```

The attribute (`'@'`) binding creates a watcher that copies the value from the template to the isolate scope every digest cycle. The modification of `scope.myVal` in the preLink function gets overridden by the watcher on the next digest cycle.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you are passing variables only for **values** with '**@**' 
if you replace it with '**=**' they **will be passed as variable and will be updated**

so, change your code in this way

```
app.directive("firstDirective",function(){
    return {
            template:'<second-directive val-new="myVal"></second-directive>',
            scope:{
                myVal:'='
            },
            //transclude:true,
            link: {
                pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
                        scope.myVal=scope.myVal+"1";
                    }
            }
    }
});

app.directive("secondDirective",function(){
    return{
        scope:{
            valNew:'='
        },

        link:{
            pre:function(scope,elem,attr){
                    console.log(scope.valNew);
                }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried with the code you suggested, the second directive is created as `<second-directive val-new="{{myVal}}" class="ng-isolate-scope"></second-directive>`

Comment: in second directive you must use as a normal variable! not val-new="{{myVal}}" but val-new="myVal"

Comment: Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '9' in attribute 'myVal' used with directive 'firstDirective' is non-assignable!

Comment: @georgeawg in stead of 9 you must use a variable, if you want use a number in first directive change into '@'

Comment: @SamGhatak can you give me a feedback please? did you try it?

Comment: @FarukT It does not seem to work that way, I get the resulting HTML as `<second-directive val-new="myVal" class="ng-isolate-scope"></second-directive>`

Comment: Hi @georgeawg , I didn't get this error. Can you please suggest anything?